# HP V1910-48G cannot route to Internet from VLANs

Tags: routing, vlan, internet, sonicwall, hp

I have an HP V1910-48G and SonicWALL TZ 105 set up with two VLANs that should be able to reach the Internet but they cannot.

My network configuration:

VLAN 1 - 192.168.1.0/24 - Transport Network

VLAN 50 - 192.168.50.0/24 - Infrastructure 1 (Ideally can reach and be reached from Internet)

VLAN 100 - 192.168.100.0/24 - Infrastructure 2 (Ideally can reach and be reached from Internet)

192.168.1.1 - SonicWALL LAN interface

192.168.1.254 - Switch VLAN interface

192.168.50.1 - Switch VLAN interface

192.168.100.1 - Switch VLAN interface

The odd thing is that a client in one of the infrastructure networks, say, 192.168.50.55 can ping every VLAN interface i.e. 192.168.50.1, 192.168.100.1, 192.168.1.254 but cannot ping the SonicWALL at 192.168.1.1. Even stranger is that using the diagnostic tools on both the SonicWALL and the Switch, I can ping both devices from eachother i.e. SonicWALL can ping 192.168.1.254 and Switch can ping 192.168.1.1. So I know there is connectivity.

It seems as if the issue is either my VLAN membership/tagging configuration or routing configuration on the HP Switch or a combination of the two.

VLAN Setup:
[image]
VLAN Interfaces:
[image]
Routing:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It might be that the firewall doesn't know how to get to vlan 50 or vlan 100.  Did you add routes to the firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ron

That was it. Forgot that packets would not know how to get back to the source IP.

Created two static routes on SonicWALL with gateway 192.168.1.254 for networks 192.168.50.0/24 and 192.168.100.0/24.